# Firebase multiple query not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a nested query for one of my tables, but it ends up returning all the values in the table where `date` is bigger instead of returning all the values in the table where `userId = userId` and `date` is bigger

```
DatabaseReference tableAttendObject = getDatabaseTableWith(Constants.tableAttendObject);
Query query = tableAttendObject.orderByChild(Constants.AttendObjectUserUUID).equalTo(userId);
query = query.getRef().orderByChild(Constants.AttendObjectEventDate).startAt(date);

 query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 //return logic
```

My data model in the table is like this:

```
->id->userId
    ->date
```

Comment: You can only order/filter on a single property in Firebase Queries. @uguboz's answer show one solution that may work, but also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 2):

If you already know userID why you are making a query?? 
Just do this

```
Query query = tableAttendObject.child(userId)
.orderByChild(Constants.AttendObjectEventDate)
.startAt(date).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
....
```

Comment: this works only in the case the `id = userId` and I have to retrieve only one object ... in my case `id` is a different id and can be several instances of it

Comment: Aha ok. Then change your database schema. Remove user ID from orders. And add order id's to the user's node such as for user 1: { order1id: true; order2id:true etc. } this way you can identify the orders belong to any user